# Problem of displaying data into custom listView

Tags: android

I'm not good at using Custom Listview but I want to display my SQLite data into it.When I try it doesn't show me any thing in List.

thanks, guys to tell me what is the problem in advance:

Rq: Retrieving data works fine And my table has 3 rows :
[image]

my source code:

new_facture.java:

```
Databasehelper mydatabase;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> itemList;
    ArrayList<Product> arrayList;
    CustomAdaptorLP customAdaptorLP;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_facture);
        ListView LP = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.productLV);
   mydatabase = new Databasehelper(this);///-----Inialisation de base
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList = mydatabase.getallProductdataintolist();
        customAdaptorLP = new CustomAdaptorLP(this,arrayList);
        Product product = new Product();
            Log.d("stat", " offline mode");
            LP.setAdapter(customAdaptorLP);
```

CustomAdaptorLP.java::

```
        private Activity activity;
            private ArrayList<Product> Items;
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            TextView tvId,tvname,tvprix;
            Product sm;
            public CustomAdaptorLP(Activity activity, ArrayList<Product> items) {
                this.activity = activity;
                this.Items = items;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Product getItem(int position) {
                return Items.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(inflater == null){
                    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                }
                if(convertView==null){
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lp_layout,null);
                }
                tvId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_product);
                tvname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_product);
                tvprix = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prix_product);
                sm = Items.get(position);
                tvId.setText(sm.id);
                tvname.setText(sm.produit);
                tvprix.setText(sm.prix);
                return convertView;
            }


    and Product is a class has 3 Strings id/produit/prix with GET/SET and those two constructs:

    public Product(String id, String produit, String prix) {
            this.id = id;
            this.produit = produit;
            this.prix = prix;
        }

        public Product() {

        }
```

Databasehelper.java

```
public ArrayList<Product> getallProductdataintolist(){

        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "select * from " + Table2;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db .rawQuery(sql,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Product sm = new Product();
                sm.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                sm.setProduit(cursor.getString(1));
                sm.setPrix(cursor.getString(2));


            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you return **0** in `getCount()` method instead `Items.size();` change your Adapter class method like below.

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Items.size();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but still don't work and I changed from CustomAdapterLP.java 
`sm = Items.get(position);`
        `tvId.setText(sm.getId());``tvname.setText(sm.getProduit());`
        
        `tvprix.setText(sm.getPrix());`
but not works

Comment: @bbazeae Are you sure your `ArrayList<Product> Items` not empty?

Comment: I found that the return of `getallProductdataintolist()` list: size = 0 I feel like my problem is `Product sm = new Product();`

Comment: @bbazeae I think you need to add `Product` object in in `list` in `getallProductdataintolist()` in while loop e.g `list.add(sm);`